# Changing characters and reversing chained lists. (python)

Tags: python, list, chained

Well, I was supposed to do the following:

Using the class Node (classic construction)...

```
    class No: 
      def __init__(self, valor, prox): 
        self.valor = valor 
        self.prox = prox
```

to make a function that when called will swap the 2nd and 3rd characters of a chained list and add a backward chained list to the end of the original one. So if we do function(list), being lista = No(1, No(4, No(2, None))) (1>4>2) it will return (1>2>4>4>2>1).

The problem with that is that I solved the problem by adding the terms to regular lists and messing with them there. However, then I found out I was supposed to only use chained lists (that node class I put above) and now I'm a bit clueless...

Code for the wrong solution:

```
class No: 
def __init__(self, valor, prox): 
    self.valor = valor 
    self.prox = prox  


def printLista(lista):
    global lista1
    lista1 = []
    while lista:
        lista1.append(lista.valor)
        lista = lista.prox
    return lista1


def printbackwards(lista):
    global lista2
    if lista == None: return
    printbackwards(lista.prox)
    lista2.append(lista.valor)


def swapprint(lista):
    global lista1, lista2
    i = 0
    lista2 = []
    printlist(lista)
    printbackwards(lista)
    for i in range(len(lista1)):
        print lista1[i], lista2[i],



lista = No(3, No(1, No(4, No(2, None))))
swapprint(lista)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class No:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
       self.val = a
       self.next = b
    def __str__(self):
       return "%s->%s"%(self.val,self.next)

def swapandReverse(lista):
   n2 = lista.next #2nd element
   n2.val,n2.next.val = n2.next.val,n2.val #swap 2,3
   n = lista #root node
   v = [] #hold our values
   while n.next:
      v.append(n.val) #add our value to list
      n = n.next #move to next node
   v.append(n.val) #append value of last node in the list
   while len(v): #as long as we have values left in list
      n.next = No(v.pop(-1),None) #set next to new node with our val
      n = n.next


lista = No(3,No(1,No(4,No(2,None))))
print lista
swapandReverse(lista)
print lista
```

at least something like that

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to use global variables for your linked-list operations. Instead, you just need to recurse in the right way, and return any values up the call-stack. I'm not sure if I've understood what you're supposed to do, since your `print` functions don't actually print anything, but here's what you can do if you are supposed to create a new list from an old one:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self): # borrowed from Joran Beasley's answer
        return "%s->%s" % (self.value, self.next)


def reverse_linked_list(lst, tail=None):
    if lst is None:
        return tail
    else:
        return reverse_linked_list(lst.next, Node(lst.value, tail))

def swap_23_linked_list(lst):
    try:
        second = lst.next
        third = second.next
    except AttributeError: # probably lst or lst.next is None!
        raise ValueError("list is too sort to swap second and third values")

    new_third = Node(second.value, third.next) # reuse all the nodes past third!
    new_second = Node(third.value, new_third)
    new_first = Node(lst.value, new_second)

    return new_first
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list_1 = Node(3, Node(1, Node(4, Node(2))))
>>> print(list_1)
3->1->4->2->None
>>> list_2 = reverse_linked_list(list_1)
>>> print(list_2)
2->4->1->3->None
>>> list_3 = swap_23_linked_list(list_2)
>>> print(list_3)
2->1->4->3->None
```